# insert data from sql file H2 database spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm trying to insert data from sql file using h2 database and spring boot .
when I add the sql file into `src/main/ressources`, I succeeded to create the table and insert data into it.
but when I create a model class named Employee which refer to the table, I can create the tables but there is no rows inserted .

SQL file:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (   id INT AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,  
first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,   last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,  
mail VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,   password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL ); 
INSERT INTO employees (first_name, last_name, mail, password) VALUES  
 ('Laurent', 'GINA', 'laurentgina@mail.com', 'laurent');
```

model:

```java
import javax.persistence.Column; import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue; import
javax.persistence.GenerationType; import javax.persistence.Id; import
javax.persistence.Table;
 
import lombok.Data;
 
@Data @Entity @Table(name = "employees")
 
public class Employee {
    
    @Id     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)     
    private Long id;        
    @Column(name="first_name")  
    private String first_name;
    @Column(name="last_name")   
    private String last_name;   
    private String mail;    
    private String password;    

}
```

application.properties

```
#Global configuration
spring.application.name=api

#Tomcat configuration
server.port=9000

#Log level configuration
logging.level.root=ERROR
logging.level.com.openclassrooms=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat=INFO

#H2 Configuration
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to initialize the database with spring boot:

1. **Initialize a Database Using JPA**
2. **Initialize a Database Using Hibernate**
3. **Initialize a Database using basic SQL scripts**

For your information: you should separate the ***schema*** from the ***data***,
so you should have 2 basic scripts:

- **schema.sql** : In this file you can put your instruction to create table.

  ```
   CREATE TABLE employees ( id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,first_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, last_name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,mail VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL );
  ```
- **data.sql** : In this file you can put your instruction to insert data

  ```
   INSERT INTO employees (first_name, last_name, mail, password) VALUES ('Laurent', 'GINA', 'laurentgina@mail.com', 'laurent');
  ```
- if you choose to use the schema.sql : you shoud use this property ***spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none***.
- otherwise (Hibernate) you shoud use this property  ***spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop***

For your information:

- Note: ***spring boot version <= 2.4.x*** you can choose Hibernate to create the schema **or** use schema.sql, ***but you cannot do both***.
- Note: ***spring boot version >= 2.5.x***  if you want script-based DataSource initialization to be able to build upon the schema creation performed by Hibernate, set ***spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization to true***.

**Be careful it depends on which version you choose!**
[image]

Comment: thank you for your help im gonna add this line to application.properties file
i hope that the issue will be resolved

Comment: Thank you so much - "spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true." is exactly what I was looking for many hours.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that could be causing this issue.

First, make sure that your SQL file is located in the src/main/resources directory. If it is not, then the file will not be picked up by Spring Boot.

Next, check the permissions on the file. If the file is not readable by the application, then it will not be able to load the data.

Finally, make sure that the SQL file is formatted correctly. If there are any syntax errors in the file, then Spring Boot will not be able to load the data.

Comment: i checked all these points.
the problem show up when i create the bean Employee