# Error handling class is not being triggered correctly and problem with h2 database on Spring Boot application while creating REST API

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, h2

I have been working on a simple project to create a REST API. There is a two problem on the project. Such as:

1. `data.sql`: The sql query that I have written was perfectly working on other project. But on this project it creates table but not inserted data on the table. When go I to H2 console and run the query it works fine. As I said, It works fine if I create new project and run the query table created and inserted without any problem.
2. `DogNotFoundException.java`: This class is used to handle error. If an `id` is requested that doesn’t exist, appropriately handle the error. But when I run the application and enter the wrong `id` the message doesn't appear. If no error was handled manually by default it gives Whitelabel Error Page and this is what happens if I enter wrong `id`.

[Link of the Project](https://github.com/SakibvHossain/Web-Services-and-APIs/tree/main/1.%20REST%20APIs/lab2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first one** is a duplicate of this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74088975/insert-data-from-sql-file-h2-database-spring-boot)

To Summarize,

- You have to separate the create(on schema.sql) and
  insert(data.sql) scripts
- Add the below property on
  application.properties, this ensures the schema.sql is picked up and
  the create scripts are executed `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none`

On the **second one**,

@ResponseStatus is not a replacement for @ExceptionHandler. Basically, you use the former if you have a straightforward implementation of just passing the HTTP status code (404 in this case). If you need a dynamic message that needs to be sent, then you can use the below implementation

```
@ExceptionHandler(value= DogNotFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> returnNotFoundException(DogNotFoundException ex){
    return new ResponseEntity<>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

and on service class return the message you wish to DogNotFoundException

```
optionalBreed.orElseThrow(() -> new DogNotFoundException("Breed not found"));
```

Hope this helps